# Blurred light effect in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, effects

So I was looking through the App Store and found an app called Hyper, I liked the style of the app so I clicked on it and saw the banner had this really beautiful blurred colors effect, I wasn't sure what it was called but I knew I wanted to recreate it.

I had some trouble, unfortunately I can't put screenshots but what I tried to do to achieve the same look was use a soft brush on a black background and use a guassian blur to sort of make it similar, it did not work, it looked very weird and not as structured as the photo.

[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve this look?

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a picture of the [aurora borealis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora), better known as the [northern lights](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=northern+lights&tbm=isch).

A few minutes editing an image of the northern lights and we have this (it's not perfect, the original image wasn't very good and I spent no more than a few minutes editing it):

[image]

1. Take your image of the northern lights:

[image]

2. Add a Color Balance adjustment layer to bring out the blues:

[image]

3. Add a dark blue to transparent gradient to flatten the lower parts of the image:

[image]

4. Add some final level adjustments and some white type on top:

[image]